# Custom update in KendoUI datasource

Tags: oracle, kendo-ui, view

I'm presenting a custom database view to the user in KendoUI, but my problem is that it's not updateable. My question is as follows: is there a way to write custom update behavior depending on which columns are being updated?

For instance, say I joined employees(id,name,dept_id) with department(id,dept_name) on department_id to form a table emp_dept(employee_id,employee_name,department_name). Say I was displaying emp_dept in Kendo and wanted to change the department names from the interface (and this was somehow impossible with a standard UPDATE statement). Could I write custom code for custom updates? For instance, in transport (and try not laugh at how basic/uninformed this looks as I'm still a noob):

```
update: {
    url: function(options){
        if(updating the employee name column)
            return someserver:port/employees/employee_id
        else if(updating the department name column)
            return someserver:port/department/department_id
    },
},
```

Hopefully you get the idea. Is this possible in KendoUI?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve won't be possible on the View, but you can achieve the same on the Controller side for which you will need to pass a valid information of what kind of Update is required (i.e. department or employee)

Comment: I figured as much, @D_Learning. How do I do that, though?